# Are these two forms of factoring a polynomial the same?

Tags: polynomials, factoring

I was reading about polynomial factorization and there was something that was bothering me. If $P(x)$ is a polynomial (let’s say of degree $n \in \Bbb{N}$) with roots $x_1$, $x_2$, $\dots$, $x_n$, then we can write it as
\begin{align*}
P(x) = \prod_{i=1}^n(x-x_i).
\end{align*}
But can I also write
\begin{align*}
P(x) = \prod_{i=1}^n(x_i - x) \,\,\,\, ?
\end{align*}
If yes, what allows me to do this? Because in my mind I see different polynomials when $n$ is odd...

Comment: This works if $n$ is even, but fails if $n$ is odd.  You are (in effect) multiplying the first expression by $(-1)^n$.  Therefore, when $n$ is odd, the second expression is wrong, just as you noted (re you see different polynomials).  Note that if, instead of focusing on the polynomial $P(x)$, you are focusing on the equation $P(x) = 0$, then the 2nd expression is also okay, because $P(x) = 0 \implies [(-1)^n] \times P(x) = 0.$

Comment: Your initial claim is false and I think that's confusing you.  If we know that the roots are $\{x_1, \cdots,x_n\}$, counted with multiplicity of course, then $P(x)=C\prod (x-x_i)$ for some constant $C\neq 0$.